# Error with showMessageDialog:The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (null, void)

Tags: java

Just want to begin by saying i'm a beginner in Java. So what i'm trying to do here is call a method from another class.

I'm trying to call the method from this class

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class age {

    public static void mpd(int sub1){
        if (sub1<15)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You're too young ");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You're ok ");
    }
}
```

Here's where i'm calling the method from the age-class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class mn4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, age.mpd(5));


}



}
```

I want the MessageDialog to say if i'm too young or old but i keep getting the error i posted on the title.

Comment: replace `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, age.mpd(5));` with `age.mpd(5)` in the `main` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main method should look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    age.mpd(5);
}
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks.